# How can I draw a polyline on a canvas in android?

Tags: java, android, graphics, android-canvas, polyline

I've been trying to draw a polyline on a canvas. There are no errors in my codes, but the connected sequence of line segments are not showing.Please find code snippet below;

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.Path;
import android.view.View;

public class MyView extends View {
    private Paint redPaint;

    public MyView(Context context) {
        super(context, null);
        redPaint=new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
        redPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
        redPaint.setColor(0xffff0000);
        redPaint.setStrokeWidth(5);

    }
    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);
        canvas.drawRect(10,30,200,200,redPaint);
        canvas.drawCircle(300,300,250,redPaint);

        Path mylines=new Path();
        mylines.moveTo(0,0);
        mylines.lineTo(1,1);
        mylines.lineTo(2,2);
        mylines.lineTo(3,3);
        mylines.lineTo(4,4);
        Paint GreenPaint=new Paint();
        GreenPaint.setARGB(255,0,255,0);
        canvas.drawPath(mylines,GreenPaint);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is largely correct. You do not completely initialized `GreenPaint` like you do `redPaint` and that is a problem. The second issue, although it may not be a problem, is that your polyline shape is so small that you may miss it even with a fully initialized `GreenPaint`.

Here is an updated version of your custom view with an additional constructor and an initialized `greenPaint`. I also changed the shape of the polyline and made it larger to be easily seen - it is just a speck in your code.  In addition I moved object allocation out of `onDraw()`.

```
    public class MyView extends View {
    Path mylines = new Path();
    private Paint redPaint;
    private Paint greenPaint;

    public MyView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        init();
    }

    public MyView(Context context) {
        super(context, null);
        init();
    }

    private void init() {
        redPaint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
        redPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
        redPaint.setColor(0xffff0000);
        redPaint.setStrokeWidth(5);

        greenPaint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
        greenPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
        greenPaint.setARGB(255, 0, 255, 0);
        greenPaint.setStrokeWidth(5);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);
        canvas.drawRect(10, 30, 200, 200, redPaint);
        canvas.drawCircle(300, 300, 250, redPaint);

        mylines.moveTo(0, 0);
        mylines.lineTo(200, 50);
        mylines.lineTo(300, 150);
        mylines.lineTo(400, 250);
        mylines.lineTo(500, 300);

        canvas.drawPath(mylines, greenPaint);

    }
}
```

Here is the display. (I added a gray background for visibility of the view but it is not needed.)

[image]

Comment: Thanks for taking time @ Cheticamp. However, the emulator ought to display three objects; a rectangle, a circle and a polyline. But why is it showing only the rectangle and circle? How do I make it show all three objects?

Comment: I can't thank you enough @ Cheticamp, all three objects are now showing. You're awesome! Thanks a lot for taking time.

Comment: @IkeIsrael If you found the answer useful, you could accept the answer and upvote it (but you may not have enough reputation to upvote.)

Comment: Thanks for the reminder didn't know how to accept the answer, just figured it out now. Answer accepted. A million thanks.